# how to add adb shell command result to an variable and use it in if statement

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, adb

I use the following line in my windows batch

```
SET MOBILE_PATH=/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista
SET FILE_BILL="adb shell ls %MOBILE_PATH% ^| find /c "Bill.txt" "
```

this line `adb shell ls %MOBILE_PATH% | find /c "Bill.txt"` gives me 1

I want to write an If statement that will do something if FILE_BILL equals 1 and something else if equals 0. How can i do this?

```
if %FILE_BILL% == 1 (
    echo the file exists
) else (
    echo the file does not exist
)
```

I always get the message `file does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question makes it appear that it is only important that Bill.txt exists (or not) in a given location, and not that `find /c "Bill.txt"` gives `1`.  If that is true, then  when "Bill.txt" is in the output of the adb command, you can simply use `%ERRORLEVEL%`:

```
SET MOBILE_PATH=/mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista
adb shell ls %MOBILE_PATH% | find /c "Bill.txt" >NUL
if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    echo the file exists
) else (
    echo the file does not exist
)
```

You can save %ERRORLEVEL% to some other variable for later use.

Comment: I want to check if Bill.txt file exists or not in the given location. But I receive again only the file does not exist

Comment: I use adb shell because this path /mnt/sdcard/koinoxrista is in an android device

Comment: Whoops, that should have been `== 0`. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I commented.  Sorry.  You were looking in a different file system space.

Comment: For some reason your question has in it `^|` which I did not recognize.  I took out the `^` because it looks like an error.  Try without it.